# Netsh commands not working on remote computer

Tags: remote, dhcp, netsh

At work, we are in the process of migrating over 200 computers from static IPs to DHCP.  The DHCP server is configured.  My biggest hurdle is physically going to every single computer in the area and configuring them all for DHCP.

I am trying to use netsh to accomplish this.  However, I cannot even seem to set one computer to DHCP remotely.  The command I am trying is:

```
netsh -r COMPUTERNAME interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" source=dhcp
netsh -r COMPUTERNAME interface ip set dns name="Local Area Connection" source=dhcp
```

This results in the error

> The following command was not found: interface ip set address "name=Local Area Connection" source=dhcp.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround.  I created a batch file that had the netsh commands in it, then used WMI to start that batch file remotely.